# Access instance from inline override method

Tags: java, class, overriding, instance

I have class from a third party component as this and I need to access `poleMarker` from `onTap` but it's null and I have no access to it :

```
Marker poleMarker = new Marker(markerPoint,myBitmap),0,0) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTap(org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong tapLatLong, Point layerXY, Point tapXY) 
                    {
                        // poleMarker is null here and I need it :)
                        lastTappedMarker = poleMarker;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method (this is the compiler error and I couldn't explain it better myself...). You should be using `this` for it.

```
Marker poleMarker = new Marker(markerPoint,myBitmap),0,0) {
    @Override
    public boolean onTap(org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong tapLatLong, Point layerXY, Point tapXY) 
    {
         lastTappedMarker = this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're inside an nested-class, you can simply use the keyword 'this'.
It should correspond to the same instance.

```
lastTappedMarker = this;
```